# Java+MongoDB grantRolesToUser

Tags: java, mongodb

I use Java with mongodb database.
I need, with java, execute the mongodb command:

```
db.grantRolesToUser( "jack", [ {role:"dbOwner",db:"commerce"} ] )
```

Mind that I need pass the 'db' parameter, because at this moment, i'm logged at 'admin' db. 
So, how I execute the above command in mongodb with java code?

Comment: Might be interested in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-1204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the 3.x MongoDB Java driver series, you can use the runCommand method in MongoDatabase to execute the grantRolesToUser command.  Assuming that the user "jack" was created in the "admin" database:

```
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
    MongoDatabase adminDatabase = client.getDatabase("admin");

    adminDatabase.runCommand(new Document("grantRolesToUser", "jack")
            .append("roles", Collections.singletonList(new Document("role", "dbOwner").append("db", "commerce"))));
```