# Getting current mongo user roles in spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using spring with mongo 3.4 and trying to create databases programmatically, but before doing this I want to check if the mongo user have the privileges on mongo server to create databases. For this I'm trying to get the roles of the user without success.

Tried this way adapted from [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34636908/javamongodb-grantrolestouser), but without success:

```
MongoClient dbCheckClient = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase adminDatabase = dbCheckClient.getDatabase("admin");
Document doc = adminDatabase.runCommand(new Document("getUsers", ""));
```

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [connectionStatus](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/connectionStatus/#connectionstatus) command with the `showPrivileges` option.

Comment: While doing this directly in robomongo returns all the info needed, for some reason, doing it in a java class will result in empty lists: `Document{{authInfo=Document{{authenticatedUsers=[], authenticatedUserRoles=[], authenticatedUserPrivileges=[]}}, ok=1.0}}`

Comment: That would indicate the java class is not authenticating before running the command.